# Authenticating with a Cloud Run Service (GCP) from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a cloud run web service (flask) hosted on GCP, I can make GET requests to this server from my terminal using curl

```
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" SERVICE_URL
```

Which works, I am trying to do the same thing in Node.js using the fetch function, i.e:

```
  fetch(SERVICE_URL)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => resolve(data.total))
        .catch(error => alert('Error! ' + error.message))
```

However, I am getting a 403, how do I authenticate with my service on GCP?

Comment: What is you type of credential? Is it on your workstation?

Comment: yes on my workstation

Comment: What's your credential?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have token, which I got it using the google SDK, when I used this token from the context of a curl command it worked, if I used it from python it works, but when I call from inside node.js I get a 403 errors and CORS pre flight error

Comment: How do you request in Python? How do you request in Node? The shared piece of code is too small!